# How do I write text in subscript in the axis labels and the legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following axis labels and legend.

```
plt.ylabel("ratio_2")
plt.xlabel("n_1")
plt.legend(('alpha_1','alpha_2' ), loc = 'best',shadow = True)
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Put dollar signs around the formula: `plt.xlabel("$n_1$")`

Comment: In case the subscript is longer than one character e.g. n_10, then one can write: `plt.xlabel("$n_{10}$")`

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way I know is to enable TeX mode for matplotlib,

from http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/UsingTex:

```
from matplotlib import rc
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text', usetex=True)
```

Comment: What this does is it runs all your text through TeX, writing various files on the way. Matplotlib has its own TeX-like engine that is faster - just put dollar signs around the formula.